# How to connect to MySQL from ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to take a Mysql Instance. But getting error. here is the code i am trying with :

### Code  :

```
 require "mysql"

begin
#con = Mysql.new '127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'amazon'
con = Mysql.new("localhost", "root", '', "amazon")

rs = con.query("SELECT * FROM url")

rs.each do |row|
puts row.join("\s")
end

 rescue Mysql::Error => e
 puts e.errno
 puts e.error
 ensure
 con.close if con
 end
```

### ERROR :

```
   in `rescue in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Mysql (NameError)
```

Comment: Which MySQL gem are you using?

Comment: its mysql. install it as gem install mysql

Comment: I'd highly recommend using an ORM such as [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org), Active Record, which is built into Rails but can be used stand-alone, or DataMapper. They'll make it easier to connect to any DBM you might migrate to, but, even better, they'll allow you to avoid writing code that's tied specifically to a particular DBM. Also, [Mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) is current, Mysql has been deprecated.